# R-Squared for Kruskal Driver Analysis model

Tags: python, data-analysis

I wrote and created the model, but not sure how to get the R-Squared for that,

```js
Kruskals.from_pandas_df(df1,independent_cols,dependent_col).driver_score_to_series(percentage=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate R-squared you need to have the true values of the variable you are trying to predict and your models predictions. You can use sklearn implementation for calculating it. Just put in the true values and predictions.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html